# How to validate rest path (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, restful-authentication

How to validate path variables (storeId,customerId,accountId) given from the following URL or anything similar ?

`/store/{storeId}/customers/{customerId}/accounts/{accountId}`

In case a user starts writing `random storeIds/customerIds`, and try to create resources like 
`POST /store/478489/customers/56423/accounts` (supposing 478489 and 56423 don't point to a valid resource) in the URL. 
I want to return the correct error code e.g. `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST`.

I am using Java with spring boot.

Following question explains my problem more detailed, however it does not have much responses.
[Validating path to nested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733411/validating-path-to-nested-resource)

Comment: you check if the resource exists, if it doesn't you throw an exception, catch that exception in a ControllerAdvice and map it to a http status code that you return to the calling client.

Comment: So I should go through every id and if each of them exists only than perform the requested action (put, post, get) ?

Comment: well you need to validate each of them, so you take them all, you do your lookup in you database and if one of them is missing, you throw an exception

Comment: Okay, I can validate if each id exists with crudrepository, however I want to check if customerId belongs to that particular store so I need extra queries to check that ? Does spring boot way jpa provida a way to check them all  ?

Comment: You can validate everything with a single query such as `select a from Account a where a.id = :accountId and a.customer.id = :customerId && a.customer.store.id = :storeId`. Or, if the account ID is unique, you can load the account by ID, and check that its store and its customer have the IDs passed in the path variables.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided URL `/store/{storeId}/customers/{customerId}/accounts/{accountId}`,
It is evident that `store has customers` and those `customers have accounts`.

Following approach includes extra database calls for validating store by ID and customer by ID, but that would be the appropriate approach because if we use query with joins on STORE and CUSTOMER tables then you might not be able to exactly tell if given storeId or customerId is incorrect/not in database.

If you go step by step you can show appropriate error messages,

If storeId is incorrect - `There exists no store with given storeId: XYZ`
If customerId is incorrect - `There exists no customer with customerID: XYZ`

Since, you mentioned that you are using Spring Boot, your code should be looking something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/store/{storeId}/customers/{customerId}/accounts", 
                 method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Account> persistAccount(@RequestBody Account account, @PathVariable("storeId") Integer storeId,
@PathVariable("customerId") Integer customerId) {

    // Assuming you have some service class @Autowired that will query store by ID.
    // Assuming you have classes like Store, Customer, Account defined
    Store store = service.getStoreById(storeId);
    if(store==null){
        //Throw your exception / Use some Exception handling mechanism like @ExceptionHandler etc.
        //Along with proper Http Status code.
        //Message will be something like: *There exists no store with given storeId: XYZ*
    }
    Customer customer = service.getAccountById(storeId, customerId);
    if(customer==null){
        //Throw your exception with proper message.
        //Message will be something like: *There exists no store with given customerID: XYZ*
    }
    // Assuming you already have some code to save account info in database.
    // for convenience I am naming it as saveAccountAgainstStoreAndCustomer
    Account account = service.saveAccountAgainstStoreAndCustomer(storeId, customerId, account);
    ResponseEntity<Account> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Account>(account, HttpStatus.CREATED);        
}
```

Above code snippet is just a skeleton of what your code should look like, you make structure it in better way than it is given above by following some good coding practices.

I hope it helps.

Comment: how do you implement saveAccountAgainstStoreAndCustomer is it a query ?

Comment: Yes it will be a query, I assumed that you have some code that saves account info with relation to Store and Customer so I named method as `saveAccountAgainstStoreAndCustomer`. You will need to have some code that actually saves Account info in database.